# Circular import puzzles me

Tags: python

I have got two python files as below:

x.py

```
def X1():
    return "x1"

from y import Y2

def X2():
    return "x2"
```

y.py

```
def Y1():
    return "y1"

from x import X1

def Y2():
    return "y2"
```

I got error `cannot import name 'Y2' from 'y'` when I ran `python x.py`. Surprisingly, it runs with no problem for `python y.py`. I am so confused now. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In `y.py`, the function `Y2` is defined AFTER the import from `x.py`, whereas in `x.py` the function `X1` is defined BEFORE the import from `y.py`. You will observe the same behaviour in both files if you import `X2` in `y.py` and `Y2` in `x.py`.

Comment: So what is your question?